# Parsing stdout chunks into arrays in bash or ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, bash, parsing, stdout

I am trying to find the most efficient way to turn stdout log entries from racadm (dell chassis/idrac) into individual arrays or json arrays so I can evaluate each entry one at a time.  The output always has the same fields.  The output below is pretty typical

```
$ racadm chassislog view -c Storage -b PDR
SeqNumber       = 11700
Message ID      = PDR17
Category        = Storage
AgentID         = CMC
Severity        = Information
Timestamp       = 2020-03-21 00:02:06
Message Arg   1 = Physical Disk 0:0:15
FQDD            = Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1
Message         = Global hot spare assigned to Physical Disk 0:0:15.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SeqNumber       = 11699
Message ID      = PDR26
Category        = Storage
AgentID         = CMC
Severity        = Information
Timestamp       = 2020-03-21 00:02:04
Message Arg   1 = Physical Disk 0:0:3
FQDD            = Disk.Bay.3:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1
Message         = Physical Disk 0:0:3 is online.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SeqNumber       = 11696
Message ID      = PDR71
Category        = Storage
AgentID         = CMC
Severity        = Information
Timestamp       = 2020-03-21 00:02:01
Message Arg   1 = Physical Disk 0:0:15
Message Arg   2 = Physical Disk 0:0:3
FQDD            = Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1
Message         = Copyback completed from Physical Disk 0:0:15 to Physical Disk 0:0:3.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SeqNumber       = 11670
Message ID      = PDR70
Category        = Storage
AgentID         = CMC
Severity        = Information
Timestamp       = 2020-03-20 21:45:47
Message Arg   1 = Physical Disk 0:0:15
Message Arg   2 = Physical Disk 0:0:3
FQDD            = Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1
Message         = Copyback started from Physical Disk 0:0:15 to Physical Disk 0:0:3.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SeqNumber       = 11667
Message ID      = PDR8
Category        = Storage
AgentID         = CMC
Severity        = Information
Timestamp       = 2020-03-20 21:45:44
Message Arg   1 = Physical Disk 0:0:3
FQDD            = Disk.Bay.3:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1
Message         = Physical Disk 0:0:3 is inserted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i'd really love to read the entire output into an associative array so I could step through 
each entry in a for loop for events.  Looking for guidance in ruby(chef) or bash.

Comment: *The output always has the same fields.* But it doesn't. Some of those entries have `Message Arg   2`, some don't...

Comment: Any idea what you want to use for a key in your associative array?

Comment: no, I keep thinking in the mindset of PHP and I know I shouldn't.  I would love nothing more than to treat each log entry as the return values from a SQL query and then run them through a foreach loop but i've been stuck in that mindset too long and have always had a rough time with regex

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perl one-liner converts input like the above into an array of JSON objects which you can then process in any JSON-aware tool.

```
racadm chassislog view -c Storage -b PDR | \
perl -MJSON::PP -lne 'if (/([^=]*?)\s*=\s*(.*)/) { $obj{$1} = $2 }
                      elsif (/^-+$/) { push @records, { %obj }; undef %obj }
                      END { push @records, { %obj } if defined %obj;
                            print encode_json(\@records) }'
```

outputs (After pretty-printing):

```
[
  {
    "Timestamp": "2020-03-21 00:02:06",
    "Message ID": "PDR17",
    "Category": "Storage",
    "Message": "Global hot spare assigned to Physical Disk 0:0:15.",
    "AgentID": "CMC",
    "Severity": "Information",
    "SeqNumber": "11700",
    "FQDD": "Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1",
    "Message Arg   1": "Physical Disk 0:0:15"
  },
  {
    "Category": "Storage",
    "Message ID": "PDR26",
    "Timestamp": "2020-03-21 00:02:04",
    "SeqNumber": "11699",
    "Message": "Physical Disk 0:0:3 is online.",
    "Severity": "Information",
    "AgentID": "CMC",
    "Message Arg   1": "Physical Disk 0:0:3",
    "FQDD": "Disk.Bay.3:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1"
  },
  {
    "FQDD": "Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1",
    "Message Arg   2": "Physical Disk 0:0:3",
    "Message Arg   1": "Physical Disk 0:0:15",
    "Severity": "Information",
    "AgentID": "CMC",
    "Message": "Copyback completed from Physical Disk 0:0:15 to Physical Disk 0:0:3.",
    "SeqNumber": "11696",
    "Timestamp": "2020-03-21 00:02:01",
    "Category": "Storage",
    "Message ID": "PDR71"
  },
  {
    "Message Arg   1": "Physical Disk 0:0:15",
    "FQDD": "Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1",
    "Message Arg   2": "Physical Disk 0:0:3",
    "SeqNumber": "11670",
    "Message": "Copyback started from Physical Disk 0:0:15 to Physical Disk 0:0:3.",
    "Severity": "Information",
    "AgentID": "CMC",
    "Category": "Storage",
    "Message ID": "PDR70",
    "Timestamp": "2020-03-20 21:45:47"
  },
  {
    "Timestamp": "2020-03-20 21:45:44",
    "Message ID": "PDR8",
    "Category": "Storage",
    "Message": "Physical Disk 0:0:3 is inserted.",
    "AgentID": "CMC",
    "Severity": "Information",
    "SeqNumber": "11667",
    "FQDD": "Disk.Bay.3:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1",
    "Message Arg   1": "Physical Disk 0:0:3"
  }
]
```

Comment: I love this one, i'll have to fiddle with it in my environment tomorrow, a cursory run failed because perl couldn't find JSON/PP and getting packages installed that arent in a standard centos repo is trickier in our environment (but can be done)  The output is beautiful and it's exactly what I was looking for, that's something I can work with, I know how to deal with JSON objects.

Comment: @nizzoball It's a standard module that comes as part of a normal perl install.

Comment: A colleague of mine ended up finding the answer via python utilizing your pattern above, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Not bash, since shell is for handling files and launching commands, but using GNU awk which is often falsely percieved as part of the shell, it's simple yet powerfull programming language. *step through each entry in a for loop for events* is not really a requirement so here is a small sample:

```
$ gawk -v item="Message Arg   2" '  # queried item as parameter 
BEGIN {
    RS="\n-+$\n"                    # record is separated by a bunch of -:s
    FS="\n"                         # a line is a field within a record
}
{
    for(nf=1;nf<=NF;nf++) {         # loop all lines in a record
        split($nf,t,/ *= */)        # split lines by = and surrounding space
        a[NR][t[1]]=t[2]            # hash to a 2 dimensional array indexed by
    }                               # record no. and the item, value as value
}
END {                               # after lines are hashed, make queries
    for(nr in a)                    # for each record in hash
        if(item in a[nr])           # if queried item is found in it
            printf "%d: %s = %s\n", nr,item,a[nr][item]  # output
}' file
```

Output for query item `Message Arg   2`:

```
3: Message Arg   2 = Physical Disk 0:0:3
4: Message Arg   2 = Physical Disk 0:0:3
```

Here is an alternate ending for *match a condition im looking for in "Message" I would like to reference the corresponding FQDD*:

```
$ gawk -v item=Message -v cond=started -v output=FQDD
BEGIN {
    RS="\n-+$\n"                    # record is separated by a bunch of -:s
    FS="\n"                         # a line is a field within a record
}
{
    for(nf=1;nf<=NF;nf++) {         # loop all lines in a record
        split($nf,t,/ *= */)        # split lines by = and surrounding space
        a[NR][t[1]]=t[2]            # hash to a 2 dimensional array indexed by
    }                               # record no. and the item, value as value
}
END {
    for(nr in a)
        if((item in a[nr]) && a[nr][item]~cond)
            printf "%d: %s = %s\n", nr,output,a[nr][output]
}
```

Output now:

```
4: FQDD = Disk.Bay.15:Enclosure.Internal.0-0:RAID.ChassisIntegrated.1-1
```

ie. if variable `item` is found in `a[nr][item]` and that array elemets value matches with `cond` print the value of `a[nr]["FQDD"]` in the same record.
In SQL that would be `SELECT output FROM`*`file`*`WHERE item LIKE '%cond%'`

Comment: hmm, this could work under the right circumstances, I like the output but it doesn't seem to differentiate between entries.  Im mostly interested in the "Message = " part but if I match a condition im looking for in "Message"  I would like to reference the corresponding FQDD and pass that in a telegraf message back to our alerting engine.

Comment: Updated with what I understood from that after 15 mins of waking up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shawns one liner as a pattern, a colleague ended up finding a python 2.7 compatible way to do exactly what we want, code is below and offers the exact functionality I need.

```
import re
import json
from pprint import pprint

regex_string_1 = '([^=]*?)\s*=\s*(.*)'
regex_string_2 = '^-+$'
regex1 = re.compile(regex_string_1)
regex2 = re.compile(regex_string_2)
current_entry = {}
entries = []
lines = test.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if regex1.match(line):
        key, value = [element.strip() for element in line.split('=')]
        current_entry[key] = value
    elif regex2.match(line):
        entries.append(current_entry)
        current_entry = {}
pprint(entries)
```